# What is wrong with this Rails has_many through: structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting this error message from trying to do `@jobs = @user.clients.jobs.where(tutor_id: @user)`. What's wrong with my architecture?

> Could not find the source association(s) :client_id in model Arrangement. Try 'has_many :clients, :through => :client_arrangements, :source => '. Is it one of tutor, client, or tutorials?

**user.rb**

```
  has_many :client_arrangements, class_name: 'Arrangement', foreign_key: :tutor_id
  has_many :clients, through: :client_arrangements, class_name: 'User', source: :client_id
  has_many :jobs, foreign_key: :client_id
```

**arrangement.rb**

```
  belongs_to :tutor,  class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :client, class_name: 'User'
```

**controller:**

```
  def jobs
    @jobs = @user.clients.jobs.where(tutor_id: @user)
  end
```

**job.rb**

```
  belongs_to :client, class_name: 'User'
```

**in the jobs table:**

```
  t.integer "client_id"
  t.integer "tutor_id"
```

Comment: should be `source: :client`

Comment: You can't do `.clients.jobs`, if you want to get all jobs for that user use `@user.jobs` directly, active record will take care of the query understaind `clients` is in the middle

Comment: @arieljuod `user.jobs` is very different than the intention of `user.clients.jobs`, while you are correct that this will not work the following would `Job.where(client_id: user.clients.select(:id))` and this will be very different than `Job.where(client_id: user.id)`

Comment: @engineersmnky sorry, I read it quickly and though `jobs` was a `has_many :through` relation, now I see it's just a `has_many`, you are right

Comment: Yep, should have been `source: :client`. With that, this query is correct I think?: `@jobs = Job.where(tutor_id: @user).where(client_id: @user.clients.select(:id))`